# signalr .net client connection error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am facing a bit of an issue with signalr client connectivity. I am using longpolling transport to create a connection between my server and a .net based client. After a while(some six, seven hours) the connection dies and the client throws an error. I am trying to re-establish a connection as follows:

```
void hubConnection_Error(Exception obj)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
     System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
     (Action)delegate()
     {
         this.hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport()).Wait(5000);
     });
    }
```

Is this a good approach? I am still trying to figure out the issue on the server side, but until then will this re-establish the connection once the error occurs?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off handling the Closed event on the connection and then restarting it.

AKA

```
this.hubConnection.Closed += () => {
    // Restart your connection
};
```

This way whenever your connection stops you can just re-instantiate it (this is the recommended way).